# Add QuickTag in bbpress replies

Tags: bbpress, quicktag

I added an quicktag for my wordpress editor:

```
function generico_quicktags() {

    if ( wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    QTags.addButton(
        'pov_generico', 
        'POV (Genérico)', 
        '[pov-generico]', 
        '[/pov-generico]'
    );
    QTags.addButton( 'pov_generico', 'p', '<p class="fala generico">', '</p>', '', 'Fala (Personagem Genérico)', 10 );
    </script>
    <?php
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'generico_quicktags' );
```

But the button only show in Wordpress editor, not in bbpress's reply form. 
Is there a way to make the quicktag show there too?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

I just put anther add_action to insert the javascript in the rest of the theme (and for bbpress too):

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'generico_quicktags' );
```

The quicktags check in function already prevents wordpress to put the javascript in unwanted places!